# How to check persian character format in regex

Tags: c#, regex, persian

How can to use regex for all utf8 character?
for example I want to check this format by regex:

```
[1][الهه اردونی]
```

I used \w for checking persian character but it dosent worked:

```
^(\[1\])(\[\w+\])$
```

I also used this:

```
^(\[1\])(\[\u0600-\u06FF\])$
```

so how can I do that?
Thanks for any helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the regex

```
^(\[1\])\[[\p{L}\s]+\]$
```

example : http://regex101.com/r/cU1nQ8/1

- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like so:

```
^(\[1\])(\[[ا-ی\s]+\])$
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You just need to include the range `\u0600-\u06FF`, the pattern to match spaces `\s` inside a character class like below.

```
^(\[1\])(\[[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+\])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cU1nQ8/2)

```
String input = @"[1][الهه اردونی]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(\[1\])(\[[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+\])$");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
[1]
[الهه اردونی]
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lUJ86t)

`[\u0600-\u06FF\s]+` match one or more characters from the given list. `-` acts like a range operator only inside the character class.